# Extract the ground truth Language code from the file name

Tags: r

Would you please help me.
I need to extract ground truth Language code from a file name:

for example:

get or extract 'en' from the file name: 'Dictionary_en.txt'.

I tried so many times in vain.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?:

```
filename = "Dictionary_en.txt"
gsub("(.*_)|(.txt)", "", filename)
```

The output will be: "en" in this example. You can make a list of your files, using `list.files`, and then apply the `gsub` function.

Best wishes